# Make Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> strongly-typed

Tags: c#, dictionary, strong-typing

In my application users can search for different things in various places. The same search code could be used for different things. I'm trying to create a cache in order to avoid querying the database every time.

```
// CustomerViewModel.cs
public async Task<Customer> SearchCustomerAsync(string searchCode)
{
    if (Cache.GetOrDefault<Customer>(searchCode) is Customer c)
    {
        return c;
    }

    var customer = await GetCustomerFromDatabaseAsync(searchCode);

    Cache.AddOrReplace(searchCode, customer);

    return customer;
}

// SupplierViewModel.cs
public async Task<Supplier> SearchSupplierAsync(string searchCode)
{
    if (Cache.GetOrDefault<Supplier>(searchCode) is Supplier s)
    {
        return s;
    }

    var supplier = await GetSupplierFromDatabaseAsync(searchCode);

    Cache.AddOrReplace(searchCode, supplier);

    return supplier;
}
```

Here is my cache implementation

```
public static class Cache
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>> _dictionary =
        new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, object>>();

    public static void AddOrReplace<T>(string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(t)) _dictionary.Add(t, new Dictionary<string, object>());

        var cache = _dictionary[t];

        if (cache.ContainsKey(key)) cache.Remove(key);

        cache.Add(key, value);
    }

    public static T GetOrDefault<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(t)) return default;

        var cache = _dictionary[t];

        if (!cache.ContainsKey(key)) return default;

        // Have to explicitly cast the object to T
        return (T)cache[key];
    }
}
```

The thing that bothers me is the inner dictionary being `Dictionary<string, object>`. For a given type, say `Customer`, I know that the inner dictionary will only ever contains customers, and should be `Dictionary<string, Customer>`.

Is there a way to have the inner dictionary strongly typed?

If not, would a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<Type, object>>` be better suited? So I would check whether or not I've got something cached for the search code, and if so something cached for the given type.

I'm open to all suggestions, so if you think my approach is bad and I shouldn't even use a dictionary in the first place I'm all ears.

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out, given I'm only caching reference types I shouldn't be too worried about dealing with objects, since I won't be boxing value types. I've replaced the nested dictionaries with a `Dictionary<(string, Type), object>`.

```
public static class Cache
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<(string, Type), object> _dictionary = 
        new Dictionary<(string, Type), object>();

    public static void AddOrReplace<T>(string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        var typedKey = (key, typeof(T));

        if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(typedKey)) _dictionary.Remove(typedKey);

        _dictionary.Add(typedKey, value);
    }

    public static T GetOrDefault<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        var typedKey = (key, typeof(T));

        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(typedKey, out object value)) return default;

        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have nested dictionaries at all? Why not a `Dictionary<(string, Type), object>`? Also, use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey`

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much -- the interface your `Cache` class exposes to the outside world is type-safe. You can't really avoid having the `object` there, but it's an implementation detail, it's not exposed, and your class enforces the invariant that the type of the `object` matches the `Type` in the key, so everything is ultimately safe

Comment: @canton7 I didn't think of using tuples, good idea. I would still be dealing with objects though?

Comment: If, for instance, you want to avoid extra boxing of value types in case the inner dictionary has a value type for the Value part, you can restructure your dictionary field to be `private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _dictionary`, and then instead know in your type-safe methods that the inner `object` is actually a type-safe `Dictionary<string, T>`.

Comment: You can just do `cache[key] = value;` if you want.. and also TryGetValue to reduce the number of lookups

Comment: Why are you trying to have one cache though? Why not separate caches? And why are your ViewModels looking anything up from a DB at all? And what stops this cache from growing til it holds the entirety of your database?

Comment: "Another term for a cache without an expiration policy is a memory leak"

Comment: *querying the database every time* - every time as in over what time scale? If it's pertaining to a single thread, or unit of work the whole thing may be moot if you're e.g. using EF Core (it has a cache built in so you can context.X.Find(Y) repeatedly and it only hits the DB once..)

Comment: @CaiusJard I've left out logic in the cache that wasn't relevant to the problem, like clearing it down. Also, I'm not the project manager and so I'm not in charge of the design here. We're not using EF Core, and I was tasked to come up with a caching mechanism.